# Google Analytics isn't working with Meteor

Tags: google-analytics, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm trying to use this technique http://www.bicobic.com/posts/BkFDo4CqcSnGcGtri to add the google analytics to Meteor, but it's not working (I already checked with the Google Analytics Debugger). And I'm trying with the Universal Analytics code.

Here is my code

```
<template name="ganalytics"> 
   <div id="ganalytics"> 
   </div>    
 </template> 


 Meteor.startup(function() {
   isGanalyticsLoaded = false;

   //a scriptloaderfunction
   //if the script jsE1 loaded the callback is executed
   myScriptLoader = function funcMyScriptLoader(jsEl, callback) {
         if (window.attachEvent) {

 // for IE (sometimes it doesn't send loaded event but only complete)
        jsEl.onreadystatechange = function funcOnReadyStateChange() {
            if (jsEl.readyState === 'complete') {
               jsEl.onreadystatechange = "";
        } else if (jsEl.readyState === 'loaded') {
                jsEl.onreadystatechange = "";
        }

    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  };
} else {
  // most browsers
  jsEl.onload = function funcOnLoad () {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  };
}
 };  
});


Template.ganalytics.rendered = function() {  
   if(!isGanalyticsLoaded) {
      window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']='ga';
      window['ga']=window['ga']||function(){
         (window['ga'].q=window['ga'].q||[]).push(arguments)
      }, window['ga'].l=1*new Date();    

      var myGAJs = document.createElement('script'),
         s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            myGAJs.type ='text/javascript';
            myGAJs.async = true;
            myGAJs.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';

    myScriptLoader(myGAJs, function funcEventLoaded() {
        isGanalyticsLoaded = true;
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX', 'url');
        ga('send', 'pageview');  
     });
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(myGAJs, s);
    }
 };


 <template name="layout">
      <div>
      {{yield}}
    </div>
      {{yield 'ganalytics'}}
</template>
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer Google Analytics snippet doesn't seem to work in Meteor but putting this older, optimized style in the HEAD does:

```
var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-xxx'],['_setDomainName', 'example.com'],['_trackPageview']];
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
```

You can also do this to log client-side errors to GA:

```
// log client-side errors to Google Analytics
window.onerror = function(message, file, line) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'JS Error', file + ':' + line + '\n\n' + message]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I put that directly in the head (inside a script tag)?

Comment: Yep!   (...padding...)